# Robot framework not picking up keyword implementation

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, robotframework

I'm trying to set up robot on top of an Eclipse Maven-Selenium-TestNG java project I created, but it doesn't seem to be picking up default keywords (I haven't even tried adding my own yet).

I started by creating a maven project and adding to pom.xml the dependencies for selenium 3.4, testNG 6.8 and robot 3.0.2, then also added robot plugin 1.4.7. Finally, updated the project so maven downloads all the needed stuff.

To test selenium (without robot) I created a textNG class in src>test>java, added a system property pointing to the chromedriver.exe file in my system and added a simple test that just opens the browser and navigates to google. It worked, so now I want to use robot on top of that.

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.demo.automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>automated_tests</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>  
</project>
```

I created a file in src/test/robotframework/acceptance, with the following contents:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Set Up  Start Selenium Server
Test Tear Down  Stop Selenium Server

*** Test Cases ***
Visit google
  Open Browser  https://www.google.com  chrome
  Close Browser
```

However, when I run as maven install, I get:

> Setup failed: No keyword with name 'Start Selenium Server' found.
>
> Also teardown failed: No keyword with name 'Stop Selenium Server'
>   found.

So why is it that robot is not finding the keywords implementation? And how do I add implementations of my own keywords?

Answer (score 1):

The reason robot isn't finding the keywords is that you aren't importing the library that contains the keywords. `Start Selenium Server` is part of the deprecated SeleniumLibrary. In order to use the keywords you must import them with the `Library` setting:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Test Set Up  Start Selenium Server
Test Tear Down  Stop Selenium Server
```

Assuming that the folder where `SeleniumLibrary` is installed is in your PYTHONPATH, robot will import the library and make the keywords available to you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out I was missing a maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.markusbernhardt</groupId>
  <artifactId>robotframework-selenium2library-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, I don't need to use Start Selenium Server and Stop Selenium Server because they're deprecated.
After that, I was able to run my test by creating a custom keyword to set browser path (I'm using chromedriver):

I created a .java file within `src/main/java/demo` and added a method that sets up the property:

```
package demo;

public class Setup {
    public void driverPath() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
    }
}
```

Then, I created src/test/robotframework/acceptance/Resource.robot file and imported my library:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  demo.Setup
```

Also created a src/test/robotframework/acceptance/__init__.robot file and used the keyword I created (Browser Setup):

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup  Driver Path
Test Teardown  Close All Browsers
Test Timeout  2 minute 30 seconds
```

In my test, I invoked Resource.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource  Resource.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Visit google
  Open Browser  https://www.google.com  chrome
```